# XSLT: How we can choose multiple conditions in the same test in "choose, when, test" syntax?

Tags: xslt

I need to verify multiple conditions in XSLT and I don't find an exact already question on this topic. Can somebody help me with some examples, please? I want ot add in test to verify more situations, in the same test. My examples don't work.

```
                <td align="center" style="font-size=8pt">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="esp:DocType[@v='T2']", test="esp:BusType[@v='44']">first</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="esp:AccPnt/@v"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>

<td align="center" style="font-size=8pt">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="esp:DocType[@v='T2'], esp:BusType[@v='44']">first</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="esp:AccPnt/@v"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath has Boolean operators.

```
<td align="center" style="font-size=8pt">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="esp:DocType[@v='T2'] and esp:BusType[@v='44']">first</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="esp:AccPnt/@v"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</td>
```

The above works, but maybe in a way that's non-obvious at first: It compares two node-sets for emptiness. The empty node-set counts as `false` in a Boolean context, a filled one counts as `true`.  So the left-hand side `esp:DocType[@v='T2']` selects a node or not, i.e. it selects the `esp:DocType` **only  if** the value of its `@v`attribute equals `'T2'`. When the other half of the expression also selects a node, the overall result will be `true`.

The more obvious way to write the same thing would be this:

```
<td align="center" style="font-size=8pt">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="esp:DocType/@v = 'T2' and esp:BusType/@v = '44'">first</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="esp:AccPnt/@v"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. This second proposal works on XSLT version 1.0? This I have to use. I will try it, anyway.

Comment: Yes, they both work in XSLT 1.0. ("work" as in "they are syntactically valid". If they actually *do what you want*, that depends on your input document and what the current node is at this particular location in your XSLT.)

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, it is not clear, whether **every** or **any**
of your conditions should be met in these `xsl:when` instructions.

In the first case you should put *and* between these conditions,
whereas in the second case *or*.

Apparently, *Tomalak* thought about the "every" case, so he wrote
*condition_1* **and** *condition_2*, but I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: Yes, I don't indicate the situation. I need to test different combinations so I need to use both of them in different contexts. I need to add, one by one multiple scenarios and the combinations will be increased. Thanks.